How to show popover from selected row view in List?
I have a List where I want the user to be able to select multiple-items, right-click to show a menu of options, and for one of the options, show a popover that points out from one of the selected rows in the list. So far, I've been able to do the multiple-selection and showing a context menu with options, but the popover that's presented is showing against the 'list', not any of the selected rows. How would I go about doing that?
Here's what it looks like currently:

This is my sample content view:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    @State private var multiSelectedContacts = Set<Item.ID>()
    @State private var showPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List (selection: $multiSelectedContacts) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ContentItemView(item: item)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            .contextMenu(forSelectionType: Item.ID.self, menu: { _ in
                Button("Label Items", action: {
                    showPopover = true
                })
            })
            .popover(isPresented: $showPopover, content: {
                Text("Test Label")
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
            })
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
      ///...
    }
}

struct ContentItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    let item: Item
    @State var presentConfirmation = false
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            if let timestamp = item.timestamp, let itemNumber = item.itemNumber {
                Text("\(itemNumber) - \(timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)")
            }
        }
    }
}


private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()


Which selected row do you want the popover to appear from?

Any of the selected rows would be fine.

The popover modifier needs to modify the ContentItemViews, not the list.
What do we pass to isPresented then? We can't just pass $showPopover, because that would cause a popover to show up on all the selected items. So we need a custom Binding that is true for only one item in multiSelectedContacts. Assuming Item.ID is Comparable, we can find such an item using min(by: <) or max(by: <).
let binding = Binding {
    showPopover && multiSelectedContacts.min(by: <) == item.id
} set: {
    // when the popover is dismissed, we should reset showPopover
    if !$0 { showPopover = false }
}
ContentItemView(item: item)
    .popover(isPresented: binding) {
        Text("Popover")
    }

Selecting exactly one item this way might lead to selecting an item that is currently invisible. For example, one could select the first item in the list and scroll to the very bottom, causing the first item to be invisible.
To handle this case, you also need to keep track of which items are visible:
@State private var visibleItems = Set<Item.ID>()

let binding = Binding {
    showPopover && visibleItems.intersection(multiSelectedContacts).min(by: <) == item.id
} set: {
    if !$0 { showPopover = false }
}

ContentItemView(item: item)
    .onAppear { visibleItems.insert(item.id) }
    .onDisappear { visibleItems.remove(item.id) }
    .popover(isPresented: binding) {
        Text("Popover")
    }

Here is a full minimal reproducible example:
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    private let items: [Item] = (0..<100).map { _ in Item() }
    @State private var multiSelectedContacts = Set<Item.ID>()
    @State private var visibleItems = Set<Item.ID>()
    @State private var showPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List (selection: $multiSelectedContacts) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    let binding = Binding {
                        showPopover && visibleItems.intersection(multiSelectedContacts).min(by: <) == item.id
                    } set: {
                        if !$0 {
                            showPopover = false
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ContentItemView(item: item)
                        .onAppear {
                            visibleItems.insert(item.id)
                        }
                        .onDisappear {
                            visibleItems.remove(item.id)
                        }
                        .popover(isPresented: binding) {
                            Text("Popover")
                        }
                }
            }
            .contextMenu(forSelectionType: Item.ID.self, menu: { _ in
                Button("Label Items", action: {
                    showPopover = true
                })
            })
            .onChange(of: multiSelectedContacts) {
                showPopover = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentItemView: View {
    let item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.id.uuidString)
    }
}

